# JQuery PHP / HTML switch onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, onclick

This piece of code is somehow not working and I dont know why, im not good at php nor js just trying to make some website.

The part that is not working is this favorite button, it works like it has to work but it does not switch to "unfavorite" after click, it only works if u refresh the browser.

This is the html that is generated by the php file:

```
<a class="btn" id="fav28" title="Add to Favorites" href="javascript:;" onclick="AddFav('28','fav','add')">
    <i class="icon-heart"></i>
</a>
```

And this is the js function:

```
function AddFav(id, dothis, dowhat) {

$.ajax({
    url: ("/process.php?do="+dothis+"&id="+id+"&action="+dowhat)
});
if(dowhat == "add"){
    document.getElementById(dothis+id).className = 'disabled';
    document.getElementById(dothis+id).onclick = another_function
    document.getElementById(dothis+id).title = 'Remove from Favorites';
}else if(dowhat == "remove"){
    document.getElementById(dothis+id).className = 'btn';
    document.getElementById(dothis+id).title = 'Add to Favorites';
}
}
```

I have tried the

> document.getElementById(dothis+id).onClick = "AddFav(28,id,remove)";

but nothing happens with this, it simply does not change the onclick

what it has to do is to change the "onclick" event from

> onclick="AddFav('28','fav','add')"

to

> onclick="AddFav('28','fav','remove')"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I don't think you can override the "onclick" attribute in HTML with JavaScript. The "onclick" will always run, even if you try to change it or add another click handler in JavaScript.

Your best solution for this problem would be to remove the "onclick" attribute, and setup the click handler with JavaScript instead.

Your PHP should generate this:

```
<a class="btn" id="fav28" title="Add to Favorites" href="javascript:;">
    <i class="icon-heart"></i>
</a>
```

Note that "onclick" was removed. In your JS you should have something like this:

```
var favButton = document.getElementById('fav28');

favButton.addEventListener( 'click', function(){
    // Note: `this` is referring to the button you clicked
    if( this.className === 'disabled' ) {

        // Run AddFav as if you were removing the favourite

        this.className = 'btn';
        this.title = 'Add to Favourites';

    } else {

        // Run AddFav as if you were adding the favourite

        this.className = 'disabled'
        this.title = 'Remove from Favourites';

    }

});
```

Then your `AddFav` method only has to worry about adding or removing the favourite, which in your case looks like it's only an Ajax call. You can remove all logic from `AddFav` that changes the button and call it where I've commented out.

Answer (score 1):

You says you tried

`document.getElementById(dothis+id).onClick = "AddFav(28,id,remove)";`

but the syntax is wrong because you don't have qoutes for `id` and `remove` (that are strings) like:

`AddFav(28,'id','remove')";`

I see you use jquery.. if you use jquery why not enjoy all features. your function can became:

```
function AddFav(id, dothis, dowhat) {

$.ajax({
    url: ("/process.php?do="+dothis+"&id="+id+"&action="+dowhat)
});
if(dowhat == "add"){

    $('#' + dothis + id).addClass('disabled'); // add class disabled
    $('#' + dothis + id).removeClass('btn'); // remove class btn if exist

    $('#' + dothis  +id).on( "click", function() {
         AddFav(id,'fav','remove'); // attach new function AddFav for click event
    });

    $('#' + dothis  +id).attr('title','Remove from Favorites');

}
else if(dowhat == "remove"){

    $('#' + dothis + id).addClass('btn'); // add class btn
    $('#' + dothis + id).removeClass('disabled'); // remove class btn if exists

    $('#' + dothis  +id).attr('title','Add to Favorites');

}
}
```

Comment: You should use .on instead of .bind, as stated here http://api.jquery.com/bind/ The syntax is the same :)

Comment: Yes, yes, true... old habbit :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in pure javascript than the changing the onclick attribute to another function is done like this:

```
document.getElementById(dothis+id).onclick = function { AddFav(id,'fav','remove') };
```

Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/4ku75/

Answer (score 1):

It might be a scope problem: the `AddFav` function might not be defined in the global scope.

Try replacing

```
function AddFav(id, dothis, dowhat) {
```

with

```
window.AddFav = function(id, dothis, dowhat) {
```

This way, your `AddFav` function is global, and you might call it using `window.AddFav` or simply `AddFav`